# LLVM string input/output

Tags: c, string, pointers, llvm

I want to write in LLVM code function that reads two strings, concatenates them and prints them out. Print and Read functions are in external library written in C.

I tried this:

```
declare void @printString(i8*)
declare i8* @readString()
declare i8* @concat(i8*, i8*)

define i32 @main() {
L1:
    %v2 = call i8* @readString()
    %v4 = call i8* @readString()
    %v5 = call i8* @concat(i8* %v2, i8* %v4)
    call void @printString(i8* %v5)
    %v6 = add i32 0, 0
    ret i32 %v6
}
```

But it throws: Segmentation fault (core dumped)
I suppose I need to do some bitcasting, any advice?

EDIT: This is how I implemented my C functions:

```
void printString(char* s)
{
    printf("%s\n", s);
    return;
}

char* readString()
{
    char* tmp;
    scanf("%s", tmp);
    return tmp;
}

char* concat(char* s1, char* s2) 
{
    char* t = malloc(strlen(s1)+strlen(s2)+1);
    return strcat(strcpy(t,s1),s2);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that your C functions work correctly?

Comment: It throws segfault when? When you compile your code, or run it?

Comment: yes, when I run the llvm code

Comment: Your `readString` function is wrong, you never allocate storage for `tmp`.

Answer (score 2):

Your `readString` function is broken (it never initializes `tmp`, so it points to a random memory location to which `scanf` then tries to write, invoking undefined behavior) and will likely cause a segfault in any program that uses it, regardless of whether it's written in LLVM or C.

There is nothing wrong with your LLVM code - no bitcasts are required. The code will work perfectly fine given a correctly defined `readString` function.

Comment: @niczka Allocate memory for the string and then make sure that you don't read more than that amount of characters (keeping in mind the null terminator). If you want to be able to read arbitrarily large strings, you need to read the string in chunks and reallocate dynamically.